# Somehow getting updated state in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner in react.js. I am making a board game as a beginner project. There is a component which rolls the dice. When the dice is rolled, an action is dispatched so that the state is changed to reflect values of that rolled dice. But in the reducer, both the values of state and action.data are same. How is that possible?

I have a dice rolling component which return this:

```
return (
            <div>
                <button
                onClick={this.rollDice.bind(this)}
                >
                    Roll dice!
                </button>

                <TurnDisplay dispatch={this.dispatch} />

                <BoardContainer dispatch={this.dispatch}  />
            </div>
        );
```

When you click the button, an action is dispatched, which is supposed update the state by adding dice values in it.

```
rollDice(){
        console.log("this.props ||||| rollDice()", this.props);
        if(this.props.isDiceRolled){
            alert("Move the marker...");
            return;
        }
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: "ROLL_DICE",
            data: {
                dice: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5),
                isDiceRolled: true
            }
        });
    }
```

In reducer:

```
switch(action.type){

    .
    .
    .

    case "ROLL_DICE": {
        console.log("ROLL_DICE");
        console.log(state, action.data);
        const newTurn = Object.assign(state.currentTurn, action.data);
        return Object.assign(state, { currentTurn: newTurn });
    }
    default: {
        return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I change these lines
const newTurn = Object.assign(state.currentTurn, action.data);

return Object.assign(state, { currentTurn: newTurn });

to this

        return state;

correct values of state and action.data are logged even though console.log is above those statements. what is going on? :(

Comment: Some code style advice: It's better to have an intermediate function in `mapDispatchToProps` instead of a method in the component: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ rollDice: () => dispatch(actions.rollDice())});`. Then in the component you simply call `this.props.rollDice()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Redux, in the reducers, every time you have to return a new state.
So instead of these two lines:

```
const newTurn = Object.assign(state.currentTurn, action.data);
return Object.assign(state, { currentTurn: newTurn });
```

You should write something like this

```
const newTurn = Object.assign({}, state.currentTurn, action.data);
return Object.assign(
    {},
    state,
    { currentTurn: newTurn}
)
```

The problem should be with `Object.assign`. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: OMG what have I done?! I thought wrong about Object.assign - thought it was pure. Thanks...

Comment: No prob! Simply `Object.assign` merges all the properties on the first parameters and returns that one, but redux is not happy if you try to update its state manually